# Bad performace of torquebox on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, torquebox

I am going to integrate [Torquebox.](http://torquebox.org/)
I have read the post about rails from  [here](http://planet.jboss.org/view/post.seam;jsessionid=0319B045DC149D668026181835B57EE1?post=benchmarking_torquebox)

I have tested the source code for hello world application in rails on EC2 using Apache Benchmark tool. It gives me the result of 23 request per sec.
As in that post they have mention around 600 request per sec. 
Why I have got this result? 
Is there any additional configuration in torquebox server?

Comment: Please post specifics as to the EC2 VM type of OS, amount of RAM, region, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing to compare apples-to-apples on this benchmark is the Size of EC2 instance (Small, Medium, Large, etc) which have different processor and memory configurations.

The benchmark you referenced was for an EC2 Large instance, what size did you use?

There also may have been some tuning not outlined in the post.

I would guess you're running on a Small or Medium EC2 instance instead of the larger more expensive Large instance cited in the benchmark.